# Is it possible to store a javascript function call and execute it when some variable is set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to attach an onclick event handler on a button. But I don't want it to be called if a js variable isn't set, instead the function call should be stored and then executed when I want. 
Is it possible to do something like this?

Edit:
More description:

So  basically since the sdk hasn't loaded yet, the onclick event handler should still be called but the call wouldn't be executed and instead will be stored somewhere(in a queue may be). Then in a different snippet of code, I'll check if the sdk has loaded and once it's loaded, I'll check to see if there are any pending calls in the queue and execute them. This obviously wouldn't *lock* the browser.

PS: Basically I'm integrating facebook login using their JS SDK into my webapp. So the FB.login function will work only if the SDK has loaded, but I don't want to deny the user from clicking on the login button. So if the SDK hasn't loaded, the call would be stored and then i can manually execute it once the SDK is loaded.

Comment: Can't you just have a flag inside the event handler?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Note that I don't want to have user click the button multiple times just because the first time the SDK wasn't loaded.

Comment: What have you tried? You can return out of the function call after checking if typeof (the_other_variable) == 'unknown' or whatever else is required, and otherwise perform your normal function.

Comment: To further clarify, you can always check if there's a prototype for their SDK namespace.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I don't want to return out of the function, I want to *store* the function call to be executed once the variable is set.

Comment: Is it not possible to use some form of settimeout function? That won't lock the browser, right?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: please have a look at the edit

Comment: _“but I don't want to deny the user from clicking on the login button”_ – instead you will have them click on a button, without any immediate feedback … that’s very bad UX. I think it would make _much_ more sense to only display the login button once the SDK has finished loading and is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another suggestion with a single trigger :

```
var loaded = false, clicked = false;

$('button').one('click', function handler() {
    if (clicked = !loaded) {
        $(this).one('click', handler);
        return;
    }
    // do something when loaded === true
});

setTimeout(function () {
    loaded = true;
    if (clicked) $('button').trigger('click');
}, 3000);
```

And a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/DH6DU/.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
if (!FB.login) {
  // fastest in my testing.
  var fileref = document.createElement('script');
  // Some prefer "application/javascript".
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", **WHERE_TO_GET_IT**);
  if (typeof fileref!="undefined") {
    $("head").append(fileref);
  }
}
```

or you go the other direction, and only display the login button when the SDK is ready (since they can't login with the FB API before then).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would suffice?

```
function onClickHandler(callback)
{
    // Initialize queue array on the first usage
    if (!this.queue)
        this.queue = [];

    //checking blah variable
    if (typeof(blah) == "undefined")
    {
        //blah doesn't exit, store callback in queue
        if (callback)
            this.queue.push(callback)
    }
    else
    {
        //execute all stored callback functions first
        if (this.queue.length)
        {
            this.queue.slice().forEach(function(callback) callback());
            this.queue.length = 0;
        }

        if (callback)
            callback()
    }
}

(function loop()
{
    if (typeof(blah) == "undefined")
        setTimeout(loop, 100);
    else
    {
        /*
            blah variable exists
            execute all stored (if any) callback functions
        */
        onClickHandler();
    }
})()
```

Basically what it does is creates a loop and check for *blah* variable, it continue checking until this variable become available.
It's ugly, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something using jQuery [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) according to your explanations, but this way, the click handler will be fired multiple times after SDK has loaded. Is this really what you want?

```
var loaded = false;

$('button').click(function handler() {
    if (!loaded) {
        $(this).queue('demo', jQuery.proxy.apply(
            jQuery, [handler, this].concat(arguments)
        ));
        return;
    }
    // do something when loaded === true
});

setTimeout(function () {
    var button, queue;
    loaded = true;
    button = $('button');
    queue = button.queue('demo');
    while (queue.length) { 
        button.dequeue('demo');
    }
}, 3000);
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/PKTus/.